# how to get django-rest-framework (or django-rest-swagger) to introspect my serializer?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've used some of the Django REST Framework to create my API, but I did it with function-based views, like so:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def search(request, format=None):
    """launches an API search"""

    serializer = SearchSerializer(data=request.data)
```

Is there a way to get django-rest-swagger to introspect SearchSerializer so that I get the nice Swagger UI for my end users?  Or do I have to switch to class-based views to get that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest docs](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.3.x/examples.html#function-based-views), this is possible.
From the docs:

```
def find_jambalaya(request):
    """
    Retrieve a *jambalaya* recipe by name or country of origin
    ---
    request_serializer: JambalayaQuerySerializer
    response_serializer: JambalayaSerializer
    """
```

However, this did not work for me and I ended up switching to class-based views.